# Convert byte array to Json for posting attachment to TFS via REST Api C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, tfs

I want to post an attachment to TFS. So I need to form a JSON as shown below ([Sample Request body data from MSDN site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#upload_a_binary_file)).

> {   "0": 137,   "1": 80,   "2": 78,   "3": 71,   "4": 13,   "5": 10,
>   "6": 26,   "BYTES_PER_ELEMENT": 1,   "buffer": {
>       "0": 137,
>       "1": 80,
>       "2": 78,
>       "3": 71,
>       "4": 13,
>       "5": 10,
>       "6": 26,
>       "byteLength": 8
>       },    "length": 6   "byteOffset": 0,   "byteLength": 6 }

```
partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, StringBuilder urlBuilder)
{
    string strPath = @"C:\Users\naveen\Desktop\Bytetxt.txt";
    byte[] byTextData = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(byTextData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

I have tried something but couldn't get the appropriate JSON.

How to convert the byte array into exact JSON format mentioned above?